# Viso2 camera frames for ground robot

Tags: navigation, odometry, robotino, viso2, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am completely confused with the static transformations required to make Viso2 work with my setup, any help will be greatly appreciated.

In the wiki says: "The coordinate frame of the camera is expected to be the optical frame, which means x is pointing right, y downwards and z from the camera into the scene.".

I have a ground robot (robotino), the base_link X axis points forward, the base_link Y axis left and the base_link Z axis points upwards and I have a stereo camera installed on the robot looking exactly to the front.

I configured a static transformation between my camera (stereo_cam) and the base_link of my robot (base_link) using only a rotation so the Z axis of the camera frame points forward, the X axis right and the Y axis downwards. I also enabled in the Viso2 parameters the publishing of the /odom to base_link transformation.

However, with this configuration the base_link doesn't move in the x-y plane of the odom frame as I expected but instead is floating around.

Now, watching the youtube video in viso2_ros wiki I noticed that the X axis (the red one) on the /stereo_dow frame is pointing down... shouldn't it be oriented with the Z axis (the blue one) looking down instead?.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241824/viso2-camera-frames-for-ground-robot/) by [raultron](https://answers.ros.org/users/48/raultron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Raultron,

in the video we have a stereo camera looking downwards. You should set a TF between base_link (parent) and your camera optical frame (child). Your axis ordering is correct, but maybe the parent and the child you wrote are swapped.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0